Why does OpenAI GPT always return the same response when I ask for "random" outputs?
I'm using the gpt-4o-mini model for random outputs, but it keeps giving me the same results for similar prompts. For example, if I ask it for a "random number from 1 to 10," it almost always responds with 7. If I adjust the range to "10 to 20," the response is usually 14 or 15. This happens consistently, even when I try other models like gpt-4, gpt-4o, and o1-mini.
Here’s my code:
  const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    model: 'gpt-4o-mini',
    messages: [
      {role: 'user', content: 'give me a random number from 1 to 10'},
    ],
    temperature: 1,
    max_tokens: 75,
  });

I've experimented with different temperature values, including lower and zero, but it doesn’t seem to affect the randomness. The issue isn’t limited to number, if I ask for a "random tree," the model almost always responds with "oak" or "maple."
Can I increase the randomness of GPT responses for more unique results? I’d like to keep the requests as short and cost-effective as possible, ideally just one or two messages.
Or is there a GPT model that provides more variability or true randomness in its responses?

If you want random values, give the model a tool it can call to generate them. You can make the output noisier by increasing the temperature, but that's still not going to be random.

Do LLMs even understand the concept of "random"? The responses it gave you might just be a sample of the most common input data that it's seen.

This is a place where you might find it instructive to use a model where you can inspect the weights of each possible token during decoding; a better understanding of how the model executes will lead to better intuition about what it can and can't do. One tool you can use for the purpose is the LMQL playground.

https://www.random.org/analysis/

The problem of course is that randomness is an abstract concept.  An AI has no way of knowing what it means.

@Carcigenicate, ...that's a hypothesis one can actively test. Run the LMQL playground against a model that exposes logit probabilities (pretty much anything you can run with llama.cpp will do, or some of the older instruct-trained OpenAI models), and you can see what the probability will be of each possible token when it's outputting the model, so one can concretely compare the probabilities against what one might expect a random distribution to look like (which isn't identical for each digit -- a lot of frauds get caught because they don't understand that).

Thanks for the input! It makes sense now that GPT isn't truly random—it's just picking the most likely responses. I'll look into using an external tool for randomness and check out LMQL playground for more insights.

You're not asking ChatGPT to do something, you're asking it to complete a prompt. ChatGPT is a text generator, not a star trek computer. You give it a few lines of starting text, and it generates more text based on "what seems the most likely to follow the text I already saw". It has no idea what you wanted to ask: the only thing you actually asked it to do is to "write more text".

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You are correct, however it can handle calculations, translations, and more. I assumed it could also handle randomization, but I now realize I was mistaken. However, I learned that there are plugins or tools available that can facilitate randomization, which is what I actually wanted to ask about.

No, it can't. That's the problem: it sure as hell seems like it can but every time it gets something right, that's statistical luck. The worst thing you can do is think that it's getting things right because it knows what it's doing: it has no idea what it's doing, it can only do one trick, it just does that trick well enough to apparently fool you into thinking it's doing something else. If you ask it something, and then you ask it for the same thing again, it's going to give you roughly the same thing. I has no idea what it's giving you, and has no idea what "needs" changing.
